# Best way to delegate an element on any change?

Tags: jquery

I have an input with product units and I want that on change (including copy-paste with the mouse), it triggers a function calculating the total for the line.

EDIT: I need it to work on future lines, not just on document.ready.

I have tried:

```
$('#table_name').delegate('[id^=units_]', 'bind', function() {
```

but for some reason that doesn't work whereas

```
$('#table_name').delegate('[id^=units_]', 'keyup', function() {
```

does.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method*"

Comment: It doesn't work because "bind" is not an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply multiple events in the events parameter string by separating them with a space, but also note that `delegate()` is outdated. You should now use `on()`, like this:

```
$('#table_name').on('change keyup', '[id^=units_]', function() {
    // your code here...
});
```

You can add further events besides `change` and `keyup` if required.

Comment: Assuming the `tr` you add contains the element you're trying to select with `[id^=units_]`, then yes.

Comment: Oh, I had the misconception that `.on` didn't work on descendant elements. Thank you!!